# string into arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to put a string into array, suppose i have a string like `string a = "dog cat horse mouse"` so i want to put this string into an array like a seperate workd as it appear into the string.

```
string array [0]=dog   
string array [1]=cat   
string array [2]=horse   
string array [3]=mouse
```

or like this

```
string array= {"dog", "Cat", "mouse", "horse"};
```

I want it like this in array, so :)

Comment: MSDN is your friend. Use it. Become close to it. Then let SO supplement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Split method:

```
        string s = "dog cat horse mouse";
        string[] stringArray = s.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine(stringArray[1]);  // cat
```

Comment: why have you used single quotes in split?

Comment: A single quote tells C# to create a Char datatype, which is what the Split method expects.  If you used double quotes, you would have to create a char array from it, like what was done in Billy Bob's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method:

```
string a = "dog cat horse mouse";
string[] array = a.Split(' ');
```

Comment: so this will put all the string from a into the array? as in this format {"dog", "Cat", "mouse"};

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "dog cat horse mouse";
string[] split = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries will ensure that multiple spaces in the string wont return empty entries after splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
string a = "dog cat horse mouse"
string[] split = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
                //split[0] holds dog
                //split[1] holds cat
```

Comment: why have you use double quotes in split?

Comment: Don't you think `ToCharArray` is a little overkill for this?

Comment: I counted a space as a string - in C# you have to use double quotes for strings.. I believe a single quote would also work with a space however

Comment: Re ToCharArray - I just did it from memory where I have used tochararray() before. It could just be taken off!

Answer (score -2):

This should do the job:

```
string[] array="dog cat horse mouse".Split(new []{' '});
```

Comment: But why not just do string[] array="dog cat horse mouse".Split(' ');

Comment: @Jonners, Split can only takes an array of chars not a single char.

Comment: that line compiles and runs fine on .NET35 and .NET4... the intellisense indicates that Split demands an array, but it works with a single char.